# Multiple folders of same type in app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I'm relatively new to working with the app.yaml (for Google App Engine) and am trying to specify formats in my app.yaml for 2 folders of the same type - e.g., I have js folders in 2 locations.

My directory looks like this:

```
Site
    - images
    - css
    - js
    - subsite1
       -images
       -css
       -js
    -subsite2
       -images
       -css
       -js
```

This is what I have under handlers:

handlers:

```
- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

# site root
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

Do I specify two static_dir in each handler?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do (for one site, but you can do for two) is define a static folder, and inside of it I put all the static content: images, css, js etc.

For a site with folder structure like:

```
- code
- static
  - img
  - css
  - js
```

The `app.yaml` looks something like:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

This will save you lots of sub folder configuration AND you can later add more subfolders to the static folder.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm subdividing to make it easier for different sub-page owners to simply manage their own css / js / image files. Hoping someone can show me how to specify format in the app.yaml for say css in 2 locations.

Comment: You know you can not deploy individual files like you would on an FTP server? Every person who uploads the app, overwrites EVERYTHING at the current app. FYI

Comment: Long story but yes, I do. Still wondering if there's a way to direct to multiple folders of the same type. If not, that's fine, but just wondering if there's a way.